# Concurrent access problem in mysql database

Tags: sql, mysql, database, concurrency

Hi i'm coding a python script that will create a number child processes that fetch and execute tasks from the database.

The tasks are inserted on the database by a php website running on the same machine.

What's the good (need this to be fast) way to select and update those tasks as "in progress" to avoid to be selected by multiple times by the python scripts

edit: database is mysql

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server, MySQL ?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to specify in the question. It's MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an InnoDB table `Tasks`, then:

```
select TaskId, ... from Tasks where State="New" limit 1;
update Tasks set State="In Progress" where TaskId=<from above> and State="New";
```

if the update succeeds, you can work on the task.  Otherwise, try again.

You'll want an index on TaskId and State.

Comment: Great, this way i can do insertions at the same time? Maybe i can adapt this code into a stored procedure?

Comment: You can do insertions of new Tasks rows concurrently, yes.  And I bet you could make my code a stored procedure so you only need one round trip to the database (my code takes 2+).

Comment: I wonder what the trade-offs are between lock/select/update/unlock and select/update with multiple keys.

Comment: Just thought I would note that you can make this update atomic like this: `update Tasks set TaskId=(@working_taskid:=TaskId), State="In Progress" where State="New" limit 1; select @working_taskid;`. This may give better performance if you have a lot of contention over tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your architecture, I suggest the following method.

```
1) Lock Process table
2) Select ... from Process table where State="New"
3) processlist = [list of process id''s from step 2]
4) Update Process table set State="In progress" where ProcessId in [processlist]
5) Unlock Process table.
```

Comment: The process is very similar to that, but each python script fetch 1 task at a time.
I thought on locking the table, but it was looking for a faster method.

Comment: put LIMIT 1 in your Select (step 2)

I Can't see a way around the lock.

Answer (score 1):

A way to speed things up is to put the process into a stored procedure, and return the selected row from that procedure.  That way, only one trip to the db server.